# Stationary distribution for different types of graph

Tags: graph-theory, markov-chains, random-walk

This is a follow-up questions to posts:

[Stationary distribution for directed graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311147/stationary-distribution-for-directed-graph)

[Stationary distribution for different types of graph](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122779/stationary-distribution-for-different-type-of-graph)

The definition of stationary distribution in wikipedia[Steady-state analysis and limiting distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Steady-state_analysis_and_limiting_distributions)

Are stationary distributions of graphs with every properties(for example directed or undirected, strongly connected or sparse, periodic or aperiodic)proportional with eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue 1 or this property is only satisfied for strongly connected aperiodic graph?

If not, what is the difference for each case(I mean for example for Aperiodic or for periodic etc)?

Comment: Cross posted http://mathoverflow.net/questions/122779/stationary-distribution-for-different-type-of-graph

Comment: @ByronSchmuland :) what do you mean by this comment?! Is there any problem to post in 2 site in my account. I just want to consult different scientists.

Comment: It is just polite to let others know when you crosspost. Imagine someone who spends a lot of time and effort to answer your question, only to find that a complete solution already exists on another site. How will that person feel? If you must crosspost, at least add that information to your question so that everybody knows.

Comment: @ Byron Schmuland. Thanks again :). I insert the link of my question in other sites from now.

Comment: @ Byron Schmuland. Is my question is so bad that has negative vote? what is the reason?

Comment: I didn't vote on your question, so I don't know the reason. But the question is not very clear. I think it would help if you added your definition of *stationary distribution*.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Thanks :).I'm new to this active site.I asked you to check if there is some point I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same Wikipedia article you link to gives the answer. This is true for **any Markov chain** with finite state space.

> In other words, the stationary distribution π is a normalized (meaning that the sum of its entries is 1) left eigenvector of the transition matrix associated with the eigenvalue 1.

Comment: What matrix? What eigenvector? What Matlab computation? Please add all of this to your post and ask the question clearly. We want to see all the numbers. Nobody can help you if you are hiding important information.

Comment: Add this to the body of your question. Not in the comments.

Comment: @FatimeRahman Did you calculate the *left* eigenvector or the *right* eigenvector? Wikipedia clearly tells you which of these is correct....

Comment: @ Byron Schmuland.As I understand,It must be the left but the problem as I mentioned above is that the result is not the same as an Example.Is there a point?

Comment: @FatimeRahman Did you calculate the left eigenvector or the right eigenvector?

Comment: Ooo :) It was the right.For left I must calculate               [vec val]=eig(transition')