# stationary distribution of directed graph

Tags: markov-chains, directed-graphs

How can we calculate the stationary distribution for any directed graph, let's say this one. What are the steps?

This is the transition matrix , i did:

$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$

Comment: What is the transition matrix? (ie, the matrix $(a_{i,j})$ with probabilities to go from $i$ to $j$) A stationary distribution is a $1$-eigenvector of this (transpose).

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo i have added when i think it should be.

Comment: From $1$ you can go to $2$, $3$ or $4$ with $1/3$

Comment: Calculate $\pi$ such that $\pi=A^t\pi$

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo Can i see an example or somewhere something similar is solved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stationary distribution for directed graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311147/stationary-distribution-for-directed-graph)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transition matrix is $A=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$. By definition, a stationary distribution is $\pi=(a,b,c,d)^t\in\mathbb{R}^4$ such that $\pi=A^t\pi$ and $a+b+c+d=1$. Ie,

$$\begin{align*}\pi&=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{1}{3} & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right)\pi\\ \left(\begin{array}{c}a\\b\\c\\d\end{array}\right) &=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{1}{3} & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}a\\b\\c\\d\end{array}\right)\\
\left(\begin{array}{c}a\\b\\c\\d\end{array}\right)&=\left(\begin{array}{c}d\\\frac{a}{3}\\\frac{a}{3}\\\frac{a}{3}+b+c\end{array}\right)
\end{align*}$$

Now $1=a+b+c+d=a+\frac{a}{3}+\frac{a}{3}+a=\frac{8}{3}a\iff a=\frac{3}{8}\implies b=c=\frac{1}{8},d=\frac{3}{8}$.